# How to access Azure VM from App Service in virtual network by private DNS name?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

- VM and App Service are located in the same Virtual Network.
- App Service is added to VM through VNet Integration (preview)
- VM is autoregistered in Private DNS zone, say by name `myvm1`. And full name `myvm1.priv.zone`
- Private DNS zone is linked to Virtual Network.
- Virtual Network - DNS Servers is set to default.
- VM and App Service were restarted after configuration.

Problem is I can resolve neither `myvm1` nor `myvm1.priv.zone` from App Service console by `nameresolver.exe`

UPDATE:
Actually, the issue is even bigger. App Service is not able to send requests to VMs in Virtual Network by their Private IPs (10.1.x.x) even if everything is allowed on VMs' subnet. If the same requests are sent to VMs' Public IPs there is no problem.
[image: VNET Integration settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the existing answer, for scenario `Name resolution from App Service Web Apps to VMs in the same virtual network.` in this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances), you need to deploy your own DNS server to help name resolution.

Here are the **steps**:

1. On the Azure VM in the VNet, add a server role `DNS server`, after the installation, configure the DNS server, add Zone name such as `qaz.lab` in my example. You also can manually add an `A` record for your Azure VM in this Zone.
   [image]
2. Add the DNS server private IP address in the custom DNS server of Azure VNet. Then restart the Azure VM to make it effective.
   [image]
3. [Configure VNet Integration with your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#configure-vnet-integration-with-your-app), in this case, select the new VNet integration. After that, refresh your VNet Integration. You will see the DNS server update in your app service plan --- networking.
   [image]
4. Navigate your app service, run `nameresolver FQDN` to validate the DNS resolution. Currently, It **only supports FQDN** resolution.
   [image]

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Azure DNS is a hosting service for DNS domains. That's mean you can use Azure DNS to host your records file instead of a custom DNS server. But when you use Azure DNS, it should still use Azure-provided DNS resolution. I will update my reply if I validate this.

Comment: Does it mean Azure App Services are not compatible with Azure Private DNS Zone? VN does use Default DNS Server and is linked from Private DNS Zone.

Comment: Yeah, I think so, as the doc said, in web app integration scenario, it currently only supports to use own DNS server. For VMs in the same VNet, you can use private dns zone, but for web app in the same vnet, you should not.

Comment: Basically, Virtual Network for App Services is just wasting of time. It cannot access  VMs in the same VNet. It cannot resolve private names.

Comment: With VNet integration, you can access the VM from your web app (tcpping IP port) in the same VNet but cannot resolve the DNS name unless using a custom DNS server.

Comment: VMs do not get any requests from App Service. App Service fails to create a connection to private IP.

Comment: In app console, can you run `tcpping privateip:3389`? Check if any nsg attach to that VM subnet/nic? Also note this,`VNet Integration gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but doesn't grant inbound private access to your web app from the virtual network. Private site access refers to making your app only accessible from a private network such as from within an Azure virtual network. VNet Integration is only for making outbound calls from your app into your VNet.`

Comment: It's very confusing. If I use old VNET it does not work. If I use VNet Preview it works.

Comment: AFAIK, the existing vNet integration should also work. VNet integration makes your web app could access the resources in a VNet unless some updates on Azure or something wrong on your side. It should be another separate question.

Comment: I have also run into the same issue. I am trying to access a web site hosted on a VM in the same VNet. The AppService is integrated with the VNet. Using the Public IP, the site is accessible from the AppService and outside. (Validated using curl from console). Removed the basic NSG applied on the VM. Did not make any difference. So the only option is to deploy a custom DNS with an A record to the internal IP?

Comment: @rmchndrng , yes, you need your own DNS servers forwarding queries between virtual networks for resolution by Azure (DNS proxy).  see the scenario "Name resolution from App Service Web Apps to VMs in the same virtual network." in this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances)

Comment: Thanks @NancyXiong. But I would say that we can use the internal IP of the VM to communicate from VNET Integrated AppService to the VM. The problem that I faced was due to the fact that I had provided an invalid subnet mask for the IPV4 network configuration on the VM, which was restricting all traffic from internal networks. Yes I agree that to resolve a VM name or custom domain name for the VM, we will have to make use our own DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you need to use DNS proxies or forwarders to achieve your ask. It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances) in the scenario table.

For scenario "Name resolution from App Service Web Apps to VMs in the same virtual network.", the solution is to "Customer-managed DNS servers forwarding queries between virtual networks for resolution by Azure (DNS proxy)."

On How to perform "Name resolution with your own DNS" check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server), where your scenario is described.

Comment: It looks like documentation is outdated. There is no "Virtual Network Integration", it's "VNet integration". There is no list of VNets in there. There is nothing there to select to get "Sync Netowork" button.

Comment: Oh, it's not App Service Networking, It's App Service Plan Networking. There is "Sync Network" there but inactive. And despite DNS zone is linked to VN it says "No DNS servers are configured on this VNet."